# c# dictionary update inserts at same index

Tags: c#

Im trying to update a map value:

My Matrix class (with the map)

```
class Matrix
{
    // m = column
    // n = row
    int m, n;
    Dictionary<Position, double> values;

    public Matrix(int M, int N)
    {
        this.m = M;
        this.n = N;
        values = new Dictionary<Position, double>();
        // Zorgen dat de matrix vol zit met waardes door alles op 0 te zetten
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i ++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            {
                values.Add(new Position(i,j), 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setValue(int x, int y, int value)
    {
        values[new Position(x, y)] = value;
        //
    }

}
```

My Position class

```
class Position
{

    int x, y;

    public Position(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

My program where I can see two times the same position while debugging.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Matrix m1 = new Matrix(2,3);
        m1.setValue(1, 1, 1);
        m1.setValue(3, 4, 1);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

*Position* is a class with only an x and y value. What I want to do is update the value of a position with specific x,y values to a given value.

However if I run the function two times with the same x,y values there are two keys with a Position with similair x,y values.

How should I update the position it instead of inserting a new position.

Comment: Is Position a struct, and have you overridden the Equals and GetHashCode semantics?  That's probably the problem

Comment: If Position is just an object it's going to operate on reference equality and it won't work the way you expect unless you have the exact same object to use as the key

Comment: Make Position a structure instead of a class.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] - we don't have enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: Right, yes - it's now obvious that you need to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in `Position`.

Comment: First check if the key exists (Position).  If it exists then you can simply set the current value to the new value dict[key] = value;

Comment: On a different note: if you are using a Matrix withouts any gaps (so every spot from (0,0) to (M-1, N-1) has a value), then you might be much better off using `var values = new double[M,N]`. And refactor it all accordingly. Without needing `IEqualityComparer`, hashes and whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Position` is a class then two different `Position` instances are compared by comparing their references. E.g., they are considered different even if they contain the same values.

You can fix this by implementing `IEqualityComparer<Position>` and pass that to the dictionary:

```
var dictionary = new new Dictionary<Position, double>(new PositionEqualityComparer());
```

Or you can override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in the position class.

Assuming that equality of `Position` is defined by having equal `X` and `Y` you get:

```
class PositionEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Position> {

  public Boolean Equals(Position position1, Position position2) {
    return position1.X == position2.X && position1.Y == position2.Y;
  }

  public Int32 GetHashCode(Position position) {
    unchecked {
      const Int32 Multiplier = -1521134295;
      var hash = -5273937;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + position.X.GetHashCode();
      hash = hash*Multiplier + position.Y.GetHashCode();
      return hash;
    }
  }

}
```

Or if you implement the same kind of equality directly in the `Position` class:

```
class Position : IEquatable<Position> {

  public Boolean Equals(Position other) {
    return X == other.X && Y == other.Y;
  }

  public override Boolean Equals(Object obj) {
    var position = obj as Position;
    return position != null ? Equals(position) : false;
  }

  public override Int32 GetHashCode() {
    unchecked {
      const Int32 Multiplier = -1521134295;
      var hash = -5273937;
      hash = hash*Multiplier + X.GetHashCode();
      hash = hash*Multiplier + Y.GetHashCode();
      return hash;
    }
  }

}
```

If your `Position` type only contains two integers it is a good candidate to be implemented as a value type (`struct`). Simply changing `class Position` to `struct Position` should fix your problem because the default `Equals` for value types is implemented by comparing all the fields (e.g. `X` and `Y`).

However, if you decide to go the `struct` route I still recommend that you override `Equals` and associated methods to avoid the cost of reflection and other caveats that can occur in particular when floating point values are compared. Value types are intended as an optimization and if you don't need that optimization you risk fewer subtle errors by sticking to reference types.

Note, as you are using `Position` as a key it is important that the `Position` type is immutable.

Comment: If you're going to override Equals I think you should also override the `==` operator, or else the behavior may be surprising.